# Dynamodb mapper query failing after uploading app to playstore

Tags: java, android, amazon-dynamodb, android-app-bundle

My android app(java) queries aws dynamodb using a "dynamodb mapper query" which works without any issues in the debug version of the app.

After uploading the same code as signed aab to playstore, the same query errors out with the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.f(:63)
        at b.e.a.e.run(:17)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

As stated in the error i have double checked my query condition especially if the hash key is populated (even hardcoded to test) but i still get the error.

This is my first app that i am uploading to playstore so want to check if I am missing something.

Following is the query i am using -

```
//***** Query by GSI or Secondary Index - Contact *********
                    DbClass tableRow = new DbClass();
                    tableRow.setContact(mob10digit);

                    //Build query Expression with GSI key
                    DynamoDBQueryExpression<DbClass> queryExpression =
                            new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DbClass>()
                                    .withHashKeyValues(tableRow)
                                    .withIndexName("Contact-index")
                                    .withConsistentRead(false)
                                    .withLimit(10);

                    //Shoot the query to fetch rows with query expression
                    List<DbClass> result = dynamoDBMapper.query(DbClass.class, queryExpression);
```

Please advice if anyone has seen an issue specific to dynamodb queries where they stopped working after uploading to playstore.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I was finally able to get past this error. In the release version of the app ProGuard was obfuscating the mapper classes I had defined for my DynamoDb table. Due to this, the hash key reference in the class must have been getting lost. I had to exclude my mapper class from obfuscation by including the following condition in the proguard-rules.pro:  -keep class com.test.app.model.* { *; }